# How To Use Laravel Queue on CPanel

Tags: laravel, queue, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am developing a web application with laravel.
And I need to use laravel queue jobs.
I wrote queue job and it works well if I run laravel queue worker by using

```
php artisan queue:work
```

But in production when I run that command using terminal provided by CPanel, it stops after a few days.

I searched answers for several days but didn't find answer.
Many of them suggest installing supervisor but CPanel is shared hosting and I can't have root access for installing it.
Also some suggest using cron job but then it will create too many laravel queue workers after a period of time because it creates new worker each time the cron job calls.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: the proper way of handling laravel queue is via [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)
but if you're on shared server, you could try creating a command to run `artisan queue:work` every minute or so, or just directly run `artisan queue:work` in cron job though it'd probably eat a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron that destroys the current worker and creates a new one with the flag `--once`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work --once')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Lorenzo, Thanks for your  answer.  Actually I tried that. Here, --once doesn't mean it only creates one queue worker but it means it handles only one job in the queue and dies. Thant means the I can process only one job in one minute. So I think it isn't a solution.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong, and ->withoutOverlapping seems to solve the problem. I hosted on cpanel again and let me try

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Maybe I need a cache_driver to be set?

Comment: I tried but that didn't work :(